# Java Immutable object for multithreading systems. What do I do wrong?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, immutability

I'm kind of a dummy about immutable objects. I got the idea that they're helpful in a multithreading environment and thread-safe by definition.

But the following code seems the show the opposite!

```
public class ImmutableTest {

    volatile ImmutableObject obj;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new ImmutableTest().execute();
    }

    private void execute() throws InterruptedException
    {
        obj = new ImmutableObject(0);
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);    
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
            exec.execute(new ImmutableRunnable(this));
        }
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        exec.shutdown();
        obj.print();
    }
}


public class ImmutableRunnable implements Runnable {
    ImmutableTest test;

    ImmutableRunnable(ImmutableTest immutableTest) {
        this.test = immutableTest;
    }

    public void run() {
        this.test.obj = new ImmutableObject(this.test.obj.getValue());
}

}

public final class ImmutableObject {

    private int n;

    public ImmutableObject(int newValue) {
        this.n = newValue;
        if(Math.random() > .5){
            try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(n);
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return n;
    }
}
```

In a thread safe environment I expect 50 as result. But this is not the case. You get 50 if you take off the random sleep from the ImmutableObject constructor.

So what's the conclusion? Immutable object are thread safe "if the constructor is quick enough"? Or (more probably) I misunderstood something?

Sorry, I didn't explain my doubt properly. This is not a synchronization question, I learned how to synchronize methods and use locks. This question concerns immutable objects and their relationship with multithreading. I read everywhere that an immutable object is thread safe, so that it can be shared among threads fearless. But IMHO it's not true at all!!!
So can you please provide me an example where an immutable object is shared among different threads and its use doesn't need to be synchronized?
Thanks guys.

Comment: Why does `ImmutableObject`'s constructor sleep for 100 msec?

Comment: It's a test, mate, not the real life! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The code you supplied will always print 0. That is simply because you are copying value and never changing it, so it cannot be anything but the starting value which is 0.
2. ImmutableObject is not immutable... an immutable object has only final fields, which is what guarantees incomplete publication of state. This makes no difference at all to the code you are executing here though.
3. If I were to fix your code to what I think you intended by making either the ImmutableObject or the ImmutableRunnable increment the value then you would hit the issues described above, that is to say volatile guarantees visibility/ordering but not atomicity. To make your code work correctly with no synchronization you can use an AtomicReference.compareAndSet to make sure the ImmutableObject being replaced is the one you used as the basis of your next object.
   E.g:

```
    AtomicReference obj = new AtomicReference();// was volatile obj
... change obj access in execute to match
... replace run method with following:
    ImmutableObject curr;
    do{
       curr = this.test.obj.get();
    }while(!this.test.obj.compareAndSet(curr, new ImmutableObject(curr.getValue()+1)));
```

Answer (score 3):

You've misunderstood something.

An immutable object lets you safely share the object and *read* any methods/fields *without using locks*.

In this case, you are depending on the *mutable* `obj` reference to do synchronize in some fashion - this is not the case.

Immutability is simply an object that **cannot be modified**. Once you are modifying state, you need to perform some synchronization to ensure that what you want is actually occurring. For instance, the entire "set obj by reading obj" call would need to be exclusive, and occur in a serial fashion.

Comment: So: immutable is reading thread-safe but not writing thread-safe. Is it right?

Comment: No, immutable is simply not written.  Here you're writing the immutable object `obj` into the mutable object (of class `ImmutableTest`) `this`. `ImmutableTest` is not immutable, and that is the part that is not thread safe.

Answer (score 3):

ImmutableRunnable.run() is not thread safe:

- It reads the value in obj
- It creates an new ImmutableObject
- It updates obj

Clearly if these steps are being executed at the time, then you could get issues. The problem is not with the immutable object, it is the fact that you are mutating obj without proper locking.

The easiest way to solve this would be to synchronize on ImmutableTest.

Comment: Thanks. But what I'd like to say is that ImmutableObject is not thread safe just because it is immutable. It depends on the time the constructor takes to complete. Is it right?

Comment: ImmutableObject looks 100% thread safe to me. The fact that the constructor may take some extra time to execute doesn't change the thread safety.

Comment: But if you run it, the result it's not the expected one. It looks like some race conditions occur.

Comment: Yep there is a race condition, but it isn't a problem in ImmutableObject. The delay in the constructor certainly makes the race condition more likely to occur, but it isn't the *root cause*. The main problem, as I said, is in ImmutableRunnable.run().

Answer (score 1):

As Yann Ramin said, an immutable object lets you safely share and use the object without using locks.

However, what you are testing here is the thread-safety of *writing* into the `obj` field of class `Immutabletest`. `ImmutableTest` is not immutable, and thus not thread-safe.

Comment: So can you please post a correct version of what I meant to do?